# transformations of empirical distributions for multi class logistic regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distributions, logistic, data-transformation

I am working on a **multiclass logistic classification** problem where two of the predictors (features) have highly skewed distributions. One is *visibility* (in m), which looks something like this:

[image: visibility]

Another is *precipitation rate*:

[image: precip-rates]

NB: there are a few high-precipitation rate points that are not visible on the histogram; sample summary statistics:

```
count    746300.000000
mean          0.000036
std           0.000192
min           0.000000
25%           0.000000
50%           0.000000
75%           0.000000
max           0.017100
```

What transforms should I use to reduce skewness of these empirical distributions? I've tried the **Box-Cox / Yeo-Johnson** and **quantile** transforms. The output of the former is still skewed; the output of the latter is close to uniform (as it should be), but I lose distance information.

Any other ideas?

And, as a more fundamental question, **should I really aim to reduce skewness**? I'd like my logit model to be able to pick up on certain data "signals" such as exceptionally high precipitation rates and / or low visibility events. Should I transform both precipitation and visibility to *categorical* variables instead?

Comment: I suggest making the histogram bins narrower to give you greater detail.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I'm not sure I follow. re-binning would increase the visual detail in the histograms (particularly for the precipitation rates). but how would it reduce skewness of the empirical distributions or improve training performance?

Comment: There is no assumption about the distributions of predictors in logistic regression models. Consider that a binary predictor will be skew if the two values are not equally frequent, but not only is there is no scope to do anything different (any transform will at most affect the sign of skewness), but also (in my reading) no-one ever regards this as a problem. But it is true that skewness  of counted or measured variables may have side-effects e.g. that one tail possibly including outliers may exert considerable leverage.

Comment: In this case further substantive information would help. Presumably precipitation rate here -- with unstated but extraordinary measurement units -- is often zero because it only rains or snows some of the time. Visibility is usually just a matter of topography but occasionally limited by e.g. fog. A decision about whether and how to transform these predictors should depend not just on univariate distribution character but also on their role in your model. What are you predicting and why is weather relevant? The same comment applies to whether categorisation is a good idea (usually it isn't).

Comment: In the specific case of these two plots, you should probably either aim to reduce skewness or use a robust estimation technique.   The points in the tail of the distribution are far enough away from the great bulk of the data that the observations in question are almost certain to be extreme outliers in $X-$ space.  As a result, they will be high leverage observations and can have a serious, even dominant, effect on your parameter estimates.  As @NickCox writes (+1) how you choose to handle these outliers should be informed by the model and its objectives.

Comment: I would consider a ~log10 transformation. You may need to scale accordingly though.